# Delete ECR stamp from passport

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, ecr

I have applied for passport re-issue because my passport was due to expire in Nov 2017 which was granted on pre-verification since there was change in address in Nov 2017 with ECR stamp.

I wish to re-apply for new passport with Non-ECR stamp. How much time will it take for the complete process. Will police verification take place again ?

Answer (score 1):

It will be a normal passport reissue process with police verification.
All you need to do is submit all documents to remove ECR stamp.

If you go for tatkal then you shld get passport in a week. With normal process it took me 3 weeks.